# Can't crawl with Nutch in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, nutch, ubuntu-14.04

I use this code in Terminal:

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

Nutch doesn't work and this is these are the errors written on the Terminal;

```
bash:bin/nutch: No such file or directory
```

and

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set
```

Comment: Surely, i solved JAVA_HOME problem but another problem not solved yet

Comment: how did you solve java_home problem? i'm having same issue too

Comment: My java problem is this http://askubuntu.com/questions/510179/java-home-problem-i-cant-find-javas-path/510192?noredirect=1#comment689409_510192 and solution in this link

Answer (score 0):

**If you are linux user > >**

export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /your/jdk/path | sed "s:bin/java::")

**else**

```
export JAVA_HOME=your jdk path directly
```